# R imputation of missing value using autocorrelation

Tags: r, time-series, missing-data, lag, autocorrelation

I'm trying to fill in 2 missing values. My lecturer suggests using the results of the largest autocorrelation with the following stages:

1. Find minimal and maximum data from the dataset. Suppose I use AirPassanger data by omitting two data. The minimum data is 104 and the maximum data is 622.
2. Calculations are performed for each combination of the two missing data by finding the autocorrelation (ACF) in lag 1. The experiment is carried out by replacing the two missing data with numbers in the minimum and maximum range (`104 <= x <= 622`).
3. Imputation of missing data is selected based on the largest autocorrelation.
4. The expected output is in the form of a matrix of imputed time series autocorrelation results.

I'm trying to calculate it using R, but the code I used found an error and I'm confused about continuing this. Here is the code

```
AirPassengers[43]<-NA
AirPassengers[100]<-NA
Fun_mv = function(g,h){
  g=104:622
  n=length(g)
  empty_matrix=matrix(nrow = n, ncol = n, dimnames = list(g,g))
  for (i in g){
    for (j in g){
      AirPassengers[43]=i
      AirPassengers[100]=j
      empty_matrix[i,j]=acf(AirPassengers)$acf[2]
    }
  }
}
h=outer(g,g,FUN = Fun_mv);h
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

get the correct code

Comment: `g=104:622` should be outside the function, before the call to `outer`. Like this you are passing an argument that is rewritten in the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for a call to `outer`, the function's double loop already does it.
Note that the assignment of `NA` to `AirPassengers[43]` is outside the inner loop. And that `acf(., plot = FALSE)` saves a lot of time.

```r
Fun_mv <- function(g, h){
  n <- length(g)
  empty_matrix <- matrix(nrow = n, ncol = n, dimnames = list(g, g))
  for (i in seq_along(g)){
    AirPassengers[43] <- g[i]
    for (j in seq_along(g)){
      AirPassengers[100] <- h[j]
      empty_matrix[i, j] <- acf(AirPassengers, plot = FALSE)$acf[2]
    }
  }
  empty_matrix
}

AirPassengers[43] <- NA
AirPassengers[100] <- NA
g <- 104:622
h <- Fun_mv(g, g)

str(h)
#>  num [1:519, 1:519] 0.871 0.871 0.871 0.871 0.871 ...
#>  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#>   ..$ : chr [1:519] "104" "105" "106" "107" ...
#>   ..$ : chr [1:519] "104" "105" "106" "107" ...
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I found that `seq_along(g)` is data in range 1:519, how can I change it to data in range 104:622? I was trying to use `seq()` and `seq_range()` but got an error `Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, j, value = acf(AirPassengers, plot = FALSE)$acf[2]) : subscript out of bounds`

Comment: @nahhhhh You are right, it was a bug. `seq_along(g)` is meant to have the matrix correctly indexed, to assign the values in 104:622 I have corrected the code to assign `g[i]` and `h[i]` to `AirPassengers[.]`..